# How to refresh child form when change of focus on parent form

Tags: axapta, x++

Basically I want to refresh a child form when focus is changed on parent form.

Could anyone give leads to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look on [Tutorial Form Dynalink](http://www.axaptapedia.com/index.php?title=Tutorial_Form_Dynalink).

The easy way involves no code at all, provided the table in the child form have a relation to the table in the parent form. A record change in the parent form notifies the child form, making it call the [linkActive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa582401%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) method which then calls the [executeQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa594986%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) method on the child table datasource.